# Conexão R com MyQSL

Tags: mysql, r

Alguém sabe como o #MySQL pode ter acesso a um dataframe que foi tratado no R, eu já fiz a conexão com o seguinte script

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
install.packages("RJDBC")

library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(RJDBC)
mydrv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
conn <- dbConnect(mydrv, dbname= "" ,host="****",port=3306, user="***",password="***")
```

Até aqui, ainda não vejo os datas frames do R no Mysql.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se a conexão estiver ok, você pode listar as tabelas do MySQL com a função `dbListTables`, puxar tabelas do MYSQL para o R com dbGetQuery ou dbGetTable

Comment: Você está criando um SQL db ou quer fazer uma conexão com uma base de dados via odbc? Caso seja a primeira opção, você precisa escrever os dados na recém-criada base de dados rodando `DBI::dbWriteTable()`. No segundo caso, @DanielFalbel já explicou bem.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela respostas, funcionou

Answer (score 1):

O R (felizmente) não vai carregar todas as tabelas do banco para a memória. Se a sua conexão estiver ok poderá usar a função `dbListTables()` do pacote `DBI` para listar todas as tabelas.

Para puxar para a memória pode usar: `dbGetTable` ou `dbGetQuery`.

Se você tiver criado uma conexão com um banco vazio. Pode escrever tabelas usando `dbWriteTable`.